# Python S3 upload of zip file gives AttributeError: 'ZipFile' object has no attribute 'tell' error

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3, boto

```
I try to upload a zip file to my S3 bucket, but getting
```

> AttributeError: 'ZipFile' object has no attribute 'tell' error

```
conn = boto.s3.connect_to_region(region_name=s3region,
                                             aws_access_key_id=userid,
                                             aws_secret_access_key=accesskey,
                                      calling_format=boto.s3.connection.OrdinaryCallingFormat())

            bucket = conn.get_bucket(s3bucket)

            k = boto.s3.key.Key(bucket, zipf)

            k.send_file(zipf) //<----Gives Exception
```

What is wrong here? (zipf is my zipfile)

if I modify the code like this;

```
   with open(zipf) as f:
            k.send_file(f)
```

I get

> TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, ZipFile found

I created zip file like;

```
zipfilename = 'AAA_' + str(datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(microsecond=0)) + '.zip'
    zipf = zipfile.ZipFile(zipfilename, mode='w')

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for f in files:
            zipf.write(os.path.join(root, f))
    zipf.close()
```

Comment: as an experienced user, i am sure you are well aware of the important of complete stacktrace

Comment: @e4c5 updated my question.Only one line exception i get

Comment: Still your code is disjointed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your zipfile is created with `zipf = zipfile.ZipFile(zipfilename, mode='w')`.

Following the [zipfile documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.open), the `tell()` attribute is only defined for `mode='r'`.

There is no reason to use a zipfile object, moreover in write mode, to upload a file (be it zip or whatever) that we want read, in order to upload it to S3.

Just use `open(zipfilename, 'r')` before calling `send_file()` on the key.

Comment: I did like this ;    with open(zipf,'r') as f:
            k.send_file(f) but getting TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, ZipFile found

Comment: ah, sorry, you changed your question when I was answering to it :/

Comment: You need to open the zipfilename, not zipf.
Once more, you are working with a ZipFile object rather than a filename.
Thus, My first answer was correct.

Comment: But S3 gives following error. Do you know what is the issue here? boto.exception.S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 400 Bad Request.An error occurred when parsing the HTTP request

Comment: what about using `set_contents_from_file()` instead of `send_file()` ?